# How to get the count of checkboxes that checked inside a form tag and show the percentage in a progress bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to update the progress bar according to the count of `checkboxes` checked. it should keep updating when `checkboxes` checked and unchecked. it's better to identify the progress bar using it's id.

Here is my `Html` code

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="select_all"/> Selecct All</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 1</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 2</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 3</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 4</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 5</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 6</li>
</ul>
<div class="progress">
  <span class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success" id="CheckProgress" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></span>
</div>
```

Here is my `javascript`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var count = 0;
  var checked = 0;
  function countboxes() {
    count = $("input[type='checkbox']").length;
    console.log(count);
  }
  countboxes();
  $(":checkbox").click(countBoxes);
  function countChecked() {
    checked = $("input:checked").length;
    var percentage = parseInt(((checked / count) * 100));
    $(".CheckProgress").progress({
      value: percentage
    });
    $("#CheckProgress").css("width", percentage + "%");
  }
  countChecked();
  $(":checkbox").click(countChecked);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you've defined the function with a name of `countboxes()`, not `countBoxes()`, and JS is case-sensitive. Also there is no default `progress()` method in jQuery, nor is it in jQueryUI or Bootstrap. You don't need it either as all you do is set the width of the progress bar to the given percentage value.

To do this in the most simple way you simply need to use a `change` event handler and work out the percentage of checked boxes against the total. Then you can set the progress bar width to that. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $checkboxes = $('.checkbox');
  var $progress = $('#CheckProgress');
  var total = $checkboxes.length;
  
  $checkboxes.on('change', function() {
    var checked = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
    var progressWidth = (checked / total) * 100;
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', progressWidth + '%');
  });
});
```

```css
.progress-bar { width: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" /> Selecct All</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> Item 1</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> Item 2</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> Item 3</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> Item 4</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> Item 5</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> Item 6</li>
</ul>
<div class="progress">
  <span class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success" id="CheckProgress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you debugged at all? You can see it works in the above example so the problem must lie in your configuration. The line you've asked about selects the `#CheckProgress` element in jQuery

Comment: It's working !.Thank you for the clarification @Rory McCrossan

Comment: Sure. i forgot. now i did @Rory McCrossan

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

**DO as below**

Create function which change the progress whenever changes the checkbox, find all checkbox and checked checkbox and set progress after getting percentage.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                
    function progress(){
             
           var checked  = $('input:checkbox:checked:not("#select_all")').length;
           var count  = $('input:checkbox').length;
           if( $('#select_all:checkbox:checked').length > 0 ){
              checked = count;
           }
             
           if(checked == 0){
               var result = 0;
           } else {
               var result = (checked * 100) / count;
           }
           $('.progress-bar').css('width', result+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', result);
     }
     
     progress();
           
           
     $(document).on('change', 'input', function(e){
           progress();
     })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<ul>
   <li><input type="checkbox" id="select_all"/> Selecct All</li>
   <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 1</li>
   <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 2</li>
   <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 3</li>
   <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 4</li>
   <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 5</li>
   <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 6</li>
 </ul>
<div class="progress">
 <span class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success" id="CheckProgress" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below example for your solution.

```js
jQuery('#btnTest').click(function(){
  var i = 0;
  var total_checkboxes = 0;
  var percent_checked;
  // Get all checkboxes with class name checkbox
  total_checkboxes = jQuery('#checbox_holder input[type="checkbox"].checkbox').length;
  //console.log(total_checkboxes);
  // Now iterate over each checkbox inside #checbox_holder div
  jQuery('#checbox_holder input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    //Check if we have checkbox with class name checkbox
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass('checkbox')){
      // CHeck if checkbox is checked or not
      if(jQuery(this).prop("checked") == true){
        // Increment no of checked checboxes;
        i++;        
      }      
    }    
  });
  // Calculate percentage of checked checkboxs
  percent_checked = ( i / total_checkboxes ) * 100;
  //console.log(percent_checked);
  //console.log(i);
  //Assign width to the progress bar
  jQuery('#CheckProgress').css('width', percent_checked+'%');
});
```

```css
.progress{
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.progress-bar{
  display: block;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="checbox_holder">
<ul>
   <li><input type="checkbox" id="select_all"/> Selecct All</li>
   <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 1</li>
   <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 2</li>
   <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 3</li>
   <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 4</li>
   <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 5</li>
   <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">  Item 6</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
<div class="progress">
 <span class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success" id="CheckProgress" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></span>
</div>

<button id="btnTest"> Test </button>
```

Comment: Can't do it for a click function. but anyway thank you for your idea @Optimum Creative.

Comment: Yes, bro, you can do it on any event as per your requirement. This is just a basic example. You can modify this according to your needs